# convert an array to string php

Tags: php, arrays, string

example

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

[image]

converte a

```
echo "Number:".$array;
```

as a result I want you to print this
`Number: 1,2.`
print the arrangement cleanly
help
I want to put it in the right way, thank you for your attention

Comment: Am I only one who is finding it difficult to understand or anybody on the same track?

Comment: Okay, I have read this question 1760 times, still no clue.

Comment: I want you to print the array to string, not to give me the whole array

Comment: example :c please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = array(1, 2);
echo 'Number: ', implode(',', $array);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try:**

```
$arr = array(1,2);
echo "Number: ".implode(",", $arr);
```

Output:

> Number: 1,2

**Or**

```
$arr = array(1,2);
echo "Number: ".$arr[1];
```

Output:

> Number: 2

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use loop too,

```
$arrayName = array(1, 2, 3);

foreach($arrayName as $key => $value)
{
  echo "Number : " . $value;
}
```